# Is there a shortcut for returning the passed object in a lambda?

Tags: java

Quite simply I'm using a lambda for an easily made Map when serializing something. I simply want to know if there's a shortcut for the `(panel) -> panel` before removing an editor tip, considering that my IDE loves to repeatedly tell me how `panel` isn't used.

```
f.set("panels", ii.panels.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Panel::getSerializedName,
    (panel) -> panel
)));
```

Comment: `Function.identity()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming Panel is the class of panel objects, than a more efficient way to write this is:

```
f.set("panels", ii.panels.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Panel::getSerializedName,
    Function.identity()
)));
```

The identity function always returns its input argument, [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--).

Comment: ``<Panel>`` is unnecessary since type can be inferred